Coaxial mono shaft drone
I developed a mono shaft coaxial rotor drone. When I tried to do the hovering, it’s flipping towards one side. Any suggestion or solution on this?

Welcome to D&ME:SE.  I think people are going to need a bit more information if they're going to provide you with helpful answers.  Please bear in mind that SE is gear to providing answers to specific questions, rather that being a discussion forum.
